# Error in getting subject of mail item in Outlook WebAddin

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to get mail item subject in compose mode in below way. It is throwing an exception.

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.subject.getAsync(function(result) {
  if (result.status === "succeeded") {
    resolve(result.value);
  } else {
    console.error("Error in getting Subject in compose mode. Error => " + R.toString(result));
    resolve("");
  }
});
```

Also getting same error when accessing Cc and To people in compose mail.

Error :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 5001,
    "message": "An internal error has occurred.",
    "name": "Internal Error"
  },
  "status": "failed",
  "value": null
}
```

Comment: Thanks for raising it. is it happening if you close the compose window and open new compose window and try same API's ? And please share build version you are using.

Comment: Could you also share which Outlook client you are seeing this issue and a build number?